# How can I make integers on a join SHP file stay as INT and not as qlonglong?

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins

So I've been trying to join a CSV file with a polygon SHP file and everytime I try to save the joint SHP into a new file it transforms the type from int to qlonglong and prevents me from using some other plugins.

[image: Following join between CSV and SHP file]

[image: After I save the join file into a new shp file]

Is there a way to prevent that conversion from happening or do I have to use the field calculator and convert each column to int?

Comment: You might want to specify column data type using csvt before doing the the join, like this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298777/qgis-3-2-forcing-column-type-when-importing-csv or this https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/