# Adding delimited text layer

Tags: qgis, layers, csv, delimiter

I have QGIS version 3.16 long term release.

Today I was trying to add a delimited text layer (.csv format), as I have done many times, but when I went to make the points graduated (size) based on an attribute from the table, I wasn't seeing the correct table column appear. The only values that appeared were Latitude, Longitude, and label (I made a column numbered 1 through x so that the points would have number labels, to which I'd provide a separate image file as a key). I thought this might have had something to do with the format, so I went into the .csv file and cleared all formats.

This time, two additional columns appeared in the list, but still not the one I needed. This column contained formulas--each cell was the sum of the two new columns that just appeared--so I went in and changed it so that there were no longer any formulas. Still no luck, so I went in and got rid of the dashes that Excel had used to replace the 0's and made them 0's. I should also mention that the two columns that showed up afterwards have many blanks in them, while the column I need does not.

Anyway, I loaded QGIS back up and tried to add the layer, but I was confronted with a very different looking screen than I'm used to. It doesn't list the choice of coordinates and all of those other options that are normally on the screen. It just looks like this:

[image]

And then when I add the layer, none of the points appear on the map and the icon looks different in the layer menu (or whatever it's called):

[image]

Now this happens for every single .csv file I try to add as a delimited text layer!!! The two screenshots I included here were using .csv files that I had used previously in maps without any issue whatsoever. I Googled it and can't seem to find a solution. Restarting QGIS and the computer doesn't fix it.

Comment: It might be that some columns are being read in as text instead of actual values. How are you loading in the delimited text file into QGIS? Did you just drag and drop from the browser on the left-hand side? Try using the "Open Data Source Manager" tool, specifically the "Delimited Text" option. Also, take a look at [this question and its answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298777/qgis-3-2-forcing-column-type-when-importing-csv). If the numeric columns are being incorrectly read in as text, that post might give you a hand.

Comment: Looks like you are in the Vector tab of Data Source Manager? You should use Delimited Text tab!

Comment: I've been loading in the delimited text file by clicking on the Layer menu bar and then clicking on 'Add delimited text layer." But that is the weirdest thing, you're right, it was in the Vector layer tab. I can't decide if it was taking me into the wrong place by mistake or if it was a silly mistake I kept making at the end of a long work day.

Also, a bunch of other columns started appearing as options for the graduated rules style. I think that one of the edits I made to the .csv along the way fixed it (I gave an abbreviated version of my steps in the OP).

Thanks!